# Is Open Graph still in beta?

Tags: facebook-opengraph, beta

When I'm reading https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/634/ I can see that Facebook Open Graph is finally available.
But on my Apps Auth Dialog configuration page, I can read :

> While in Open Graph Beta, the 'publish_actions' permission can only be requested from developers and test users of your app. The 'publish_actions' permission will be ignored if requested from any other user. Learn More

So my question is : is Open Graph still in beta ?

Thant a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Graph is no longer in Beta - but is rolling out slowly.

This message should really be updated to say:

> Until your actions have been approved by Facebook, the
>   'publish_actions' permission can only be requested from developers and
>   test users of your app. The 'publish_actions' permission will be
>   ignored if requested from any other user.

UPDATE...

This message has already been updated - see https://skitch.com/sicross/g5cuq/launched

Comment: Thanks a lot for this fast and great response.